# GET-запрос TinyMCE в Symfony 1.4 при загрузке изображений на сервер

Tags: symfony, tinymce

Здравствуйте. Начал недавно работать с Symfony 1.4 (как впрочем программированием на PHP), и встала задача загрузки изображений на сервер через TinyMCE без использования плагинов. В документации нашел исходники:

```
  tinymce.init({
  selector: '#editor',
    plugins: 'image code',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | link image | code',
    // enable title field in the Image dialog
    image_title: true, 
    // enable automatic uploads of images represented by blob or data URIs
    automatic_uploads: true,
    // URL of our upload handler (for more details check: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_url)
    images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
    // here we add custom filepicker only to Image dialog
    file_picker_types: 'image', 
    // and here's our custom image picker
    file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
      var input = document.createElement('input');
      input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
      input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

      // Note: In modern browsers input[type="file"] is functional without 
      // even adding it to the DOM, but that might not be the case in some older
      // or quirky browsers like IE, so you might want to add it to the DOM
      // just in case, and visually hide it. And do not forget do remove it
      // once you do not need it anymore.

      input.onchange = function() {
        var file = this.files[0];

        // Note: Now we need to register the blob in TinyMCEs image blob
        // registry. In the next release this part hopefully won't be
        // necessary, as we are looking to handle it internally.
        var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
        var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
        var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file);
        blobCache.add(blobInfo);

        // call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
        cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
      };

      input.click();
    }
  });
```

postAcceptor.php

```
<?php
  /*******************************************************
   * Only these origins will be allowed to upload images *
   ******************************************************/
  $accepted_origins = array("http://localhost", "http://192.168.1.1", "http://example.com");

  /*********************************************
   * Change this line to set the upload folder *
   *********************************************/
  $imageFolder = "images/";

  reset ($_FILES);
  $temp = current($_FILES);
  if (is_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'])){
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
      // same-origin requests won't set an origin. If the origin is set, it must be valid.
      if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $accepted_origins)) {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
      } else {
        header("HTTP/1.0 403 Origin Denied");
        return;
      }
    }

    /*
      If your script needs to receive cookies, set images_upload_credentials : true in
      the configuration and enable the following two headers.
    */
    // header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    // header('P3P: CP="There is no P3P policy."');

    // Sanitize input
    if (preg_match("/([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])|([\.]{2,})/", $temp['name'])) {
        header("HTTP/1.0 500 Invalid file name.");
        return;
    }

    // Verify extension
    if (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("gif", "jpg", "png"))) {
        header("HTTP/1.0 500 Invalid extension.");
        return;
    }

    // Accept upload if there was no origin, or if it is an accepted origin
    $filetowrite = $imageFolder . $temp['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'], $filetowrite);

    // Respond to the successful upload with JSON.
    // Use a location key to specify the path to the saved image resource.
    // { location : '/your/uploaded/image/file'}
    echo json_encode(array('location' => $filetowrite));
  } else {
    // Notify editor that the upload failed
    header("HTTP/1.0 500 Server Error");
  }
?>
```

Единственно, вместо строки

```
images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php'
```

Использую роут

```
images_upload_url: '<?php echo url_for('@public_tinymce_image_uploader');?>'
```

Чтобы событие отрабатывалось через action
На сервер изображение грузится, однако в редакторе картинка не отображается, а в консоли выходит ошибка 404

**`GET http://192.168.0.100:8089/frontend_dev.php/ru/uploads/blobid1493701221863.jpg 404 (Not Found)`**

Однако если убрать "/frontend_dev.php/ru" то все работает. Но я нигде не нашел код, который посылает/получает GET-параметр с данным URL. Есть подозрение что это строчка

```
cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
```

но blobInfo.blobUri() возвращает значение типа

**`blob:http://192.168.0.100:8089/14100d42-7790-455f-a861-7121c966dd6e`**

Мне нужно лишь подправить URL, но я не знаю где это сделать. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Ну так скиньте тот php код, который сейчас отвечает за загрузку, либо если это opensource, то укажите ссылку.

Comment: За загрузку изображения на сервер, грубо говоря, отвечает postAcceptor.php. Просто этот скрипт выполняется не в отдельном файле, а в action, но код остался неизменным. На локальной машине кстати, без использования фреймворка все работает замечательно.

Answer (score 0):

> Однако если убрать "/frontend_dev.php/ru" то все работает.

Настройте свой веб-сервер правильно, и тогда **frontend_dev.php** само пропадет из строки URL. Скорее всего у вас веб-сервер Apache, поэтому предлагаю включить *mod_rewrite*. Смотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2

Comment: Если mod_rewrite включен, а frontend_dev.php не исчез, то следует настроить .htaccess.

Comment: Вы можете воспользоваться кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/661258/edit) и добавить комментарий к ответу.

Answer (score 0):

Как это обычно бывает, я пытался решить ее не с той стороны. Проблема была в том, что в загруженном изображении тег `img` требовал `src` вида

```
src="/images/uploads/blobid1493701221863.jpg"
```

но на деле ему присваивался адрес вида

```
src="images/uploads/blobid1493701221863.jpg"
```

то есть без косой черты в начале, в результате чего и выходила ошибка 404.
Надо было лишь слегка подправить **postAcceptor.php**

```
echo json_encode(array('location' => "/".$filetowrite));
```

После чего ошибка пропала. Всем спасибо, кто помогал ответами. Надеюсь новичкам (уж матерые программисты вряд ли допустят такую ошибку) это поможет.